# Lock usage of all methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that is accessed from multiple threads at the same time and I want to make sure that only 1 thread can be inside of a body of any method.

Can this code be refactored to something more generic? (Apart from Locking inside the *State* property?

```
public class StateManager : IStateManager
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    public Guid? GetInfo1()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return State.Info1;
        }
    }

    public void SetInfo1(Guid guid)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            State.Info1 = guid;
        }
    }

    public Guid? GetInfo2()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return State.Info2;
        }
    }

    public void SetInfo2(Guid guid)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            State.Info2 = guid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to lock like this without having separate locks statements as you have. I'm interested to find out if I'm wrong though! :)

Comment: I don't think that any of your methods are thread unsafe, why are you even locking here?

Comment: Andrey - this is a dummy example. I am doing more in the method bodies

Comment: @Andrey: That's a pretty bold assertion without knowing what might be going on in those property setters and getters.

Comment: @MattBurland then those setters should provide thread safety. This is matter of encapsulation, I don't know what might be going on in those property setters and I don't have to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
private void LockAndExecute(Action action)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Then your methods might look like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    LockAndExecute(() => Console.WriteLine("DoSomething") );
}

public int GetSomething()
{
    int i = 0;
    LockAndExecute(() => i = 1);
    return i;
}
```

I'm not sure that's really saving you very much however and return values are a bit of a pain.

Although you could work around that by adding another method like this:

```
private T LockAndExecute<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        return function();
    }
}
```

So now my `GetSomething` method is a lot cleaner:

```
public int GetSomething()
{
    return LockAndExecute(() => 1 );
}
```

Again, not sure you are gaining much in terms of less typing, but at least you know every call is locking on *the same object*.

While your gains may be pretty minimal in the case where all you need to do is lock, I could imagine a case where you had a bunch of methods something like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // check some preconditions
    // maybe do some logging
    try
    {
        // do actual work here
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        // do some error handling
    }
}
```

In that case, extracting all the precondition checking and error handling into one place could be pretty useful:

```
private void CheckExecuteAndHandleErrors(Action action)
{
    // preconditions
    // logging
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        // handle errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Action or Function Delegate.

Creating a method like

```
public T ExecuteMethodThreadSafe<T>(Func<T> MethodToExecute)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            MethodToExecute.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

and using it like

```
public T GetInfo2(Guid guid)
        {
            return ExecuteMethodThreadSafe(() => State.Info2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add what I ended up putting together, using some of the ideas presented by Matt and Abhinav in order to generalize this and make it as seamless as possible to implement.

```
private static readonly object Lock = new object();

public static void ExecuteMethodThreadSafe<T>(this T @object, Action<T> method) {
    lock (Lock) {
        method(@object);
    }
}

public static TResult ExecuteMethodThreadSafe<T, TResult>(this T @object, Func<T, TResult> method) {
    lock (Lock) {
        return method(@object);
    }
}
```

Which can then be extended in ways like this (if you want):

```
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

public static T GetRandom<T>(Func<Random, T> method) => Random.ExecuteMethodThreadSafe(method);
```

And then when implemented could look something like this:

```
var bounds = new Collection<int>();
bounds.ExecuteMethodThreadSafe(list => list.Add(15)); // using the base method
int x = GetRandom(random => random.Next(-10, bounds[0])); // using the extended method
int y = GetRandom(random => random.Next(bounds[0])); // works with any method overload
```